# Python run subprocess from parent directory

Tags: python, subprocess

Hey I've got the following directory structure:

a parent directory with `a.sh` and a child directory `py` with `b.py`.
Now I want to call `a.sh` from `b.py`. How do I do that?

My tries include:

```
subprocess.run(['./a.sh'], cwd="..", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

AND

```
import os
initPath = os.path.pardir   
subprocess.run([initPath+'./a.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In both cases I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './a.sh'
```

Comment: Try using the absolute path of the file. ie from root

Comment: @AkshayApte I forgot that this is not an option since the absolute path is variable depending on which computer it is used. Changing all such variables would be too much of a hassle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use absolute path computed from your python script's path.

```
import os

source = os.path.dirname(__file__)
parent = os.path.join(source, '../')
script_path = os.path.join(parent, 'a.sh')
```

`script_path` would be absolute path to your script and would be computed from your python script's path, so if your bash script is always at the same relative path from your python script, it will always works, whatever the directory you are running program from.

---

Btw, I advise to **always** use `os.path.join` to compute paths and **never** concat strings with `+` but use `format`. I let you check why.

Answer (score 0):

Python added the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for things like this:

```py
f_path = Path(__file__)
s_path = os.path.join(path.parent.parent, 'a.sh')
subprocess.run(s_path)
```

Assume your path looks something like this, where `repo` is in your root directory.

```
repo
├── a.py
└── py
    └── b.py
```

`f_path` is the absolute path to the file you are running, `b.py`, which is: `repo/py/b.py`. Taking the parent of that gives `repo/py`, and taking the parent of that gives `repo`. Then we append `a.sh` to that path and we get `repo/a.sh`. You can now feed this path into your subprocess command.